# How do I make this card floating glass effect in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, gradient, user-experience

I wanna know how I can make this UI card on flutter?
[image]

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 2):

Try with the [BackdropFilter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html) widget

```
new BackdropFilter(
    filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
    child: Container(),
)
```